# Rendering a 'foreign' view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of modal dialogs in my Rails app.

So I decided to create a view directory called Modals, in which I want to put the small `modal1.html.erb` files that include just the header and text of each modal.

Furthermore I want to have `layout/modals.html.erb` to be a layout to incorporate the boilerplate for each of the modals.

I render an individual modal dialog, from a different controller/view family with a `render template: "modals/test", layout: "modals"` This almost works.

The only problem is that I don't get the general `layout/application.html.erb` layout surrounding the whole thing.

What's the idiomatic Rails way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you cannot tell Rails to use the modal-layout and expect it to embed the resulting view inside the application-layout, because you basically tell Rails to use the modal-layout *instead* of the application-layout.

So either also put the missing code from the application-layout into your modal-layout (maybe by using partials to avoid duplication) or somehow nest layouts (might get messy).